# How to extract Json data scraped from website

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I used Beautiful soup to extract data from a Website. Content is in JSON and I need to extract all the display_name values. I have no clue how to naviagate and print the values I need to save in my CSV.

I tried using some array examples like this one

```
for productoslvl in soup2.findAll('script',{'id' :'searchResult'}):

    element = jsons[0]['display_name']
    print (element)
```

but I keep getting KeyError

This is the JSON data:

```
{
    'page_size': -1,
    'refinements': [{
        'display_name': 'Brand',
        'values': [{
            'display_name': 'Acqua Di Parma',
            'status': 4,
            'value': 900096
        }],
        'type': 'checkboxes'
    }, {
        'display_name': 'Bristle Type',
        'values': [{
            'display_name': 'Addictive',
            'status': 1,
            'value': 14578019
        }, {
            'display_name': 'Casual',
            'status': 1,
            'value': 14578020
        }, {
            'display_name': 'Chic',
            'status': 1,
            'value': 14301148
        }, {
            'display_name': 'Polished',
            'status': 1,
            'value': 14578022
        }],
        'type': 'checkboxes'
    }, {
        'display_name': 'Coverage',
        'values': [{
            'display_name': 'Balanced',
            'status': 1,
            'value': 14301025
        }, {
            'display_name': 'Light',
            'status': 1,
            'value': 14577894
        }, {
            'display_name': 'Rich',
            'status': 1,
            'value': 14577895
        }],
        'type': 'checkboxes'
    }, {
        'display_name': 'Formulation',
        'values': [{
            'display_name': 'Cream',
            'status': 1,
            'value': 100069
        }, {
            'display_name': 'Spray',
            'status': 1,
            'value': 100072
        }],
        'type': 'checkboxes'
    }
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried. If we can't see how you got `KeyError` then we can't forward your understanding

Comment: Break it down step by step. Do `refinements = d['refinements']`. Print that out, and it’s a list of dicts. So, `for refinement in refinements:` and again print out each one. Now you can see that each `refinement` is a dict with a key named `display_name`, which is what you want. So, `name = refinement['display_name']`. Whatever you want to do with each display name; do it for `name` each time through the loop. And similarly for the ones inside each `refinement['values']`.

Comment: You might also want to try searching PyPI for `jsonpath`, `dpath`, and `kvc`, which are three different standards for building paths as strings–maybe `*.[*].display_name` or similar. They’re all a little different from each other, and all of the libraries for them have a bit of a learning curve, but for more complex structures, sometimes it’s worth it. (I think yours is simple enough that I’d just stick with a loop—maybe as a comprehension, but if you don’t know comprehensions, you don’t have to worry about that.)

Comment: Where did `jsons` come from? Where are you parsing JSON? The sample you've given is a single dictionary with no `0` key, not a list, so if that sample is `jsons` that would explain the error. It would only make sense if you've already accessed the `'refinements'` key.